# Variable's scope doesn't stretch to another file

Tags: javascript, var

I have two html files: **log_in.html** and **edit_story_name.html** and two javascript files **log_in.js** and **edit_story_name.js**.

I initialized an object variable in log_in.js.

**log_in.js**

```
var User_Name= {value: "default_value"};    
var  Login_Password;

$(document).ready( function(){
$(' #public_User ').click( function(){

    $(' #log_in_account_txt ').val('publicUser');           
    $(' #log_in_psw ').val('publicUser');
    User_Name.value= "publicUser";

    alert("User_Name.value is"+ User_Name.value);
    window.open('edit_story_name.html','newwindow');        
});
});
```

As the user presses the button "public_User", it  will assign object variable's value to be "pulicUser". 

Then the window "edit_story_name.html" will be opened.

**edit_story_name.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></s   ript>        

<script type="text/javascript" src="log_in.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="edit_story_name.js"></script>
<link  type="text/css" href="edit_story_name.css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<input id="input_story_name" type="text" value="">
</body>
</html>
```

**edit_story_name.js:**

```
window.addEventListener( "load",function(){
alert("User_Name.value is"+ User_Name.value);

if(User_Name.value == "publicUser"){
Story_Name="_story";
}else {                 

Story_Name= User_Name.value +"_story";
}


$(' #input_story_name').val(Story_Name);
});
```

Basically, after I press the button "public_User" in log_in.js, the  User_Name's value should change to be "publicUser".
But no matter how hard I tried, the value remains: "default_value".

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript variables last only for the lifetime of a single web page.  In addition, each browser window has it's own separate state.  When you go to another web page in the same window, your javascript scripts are reinitialized again from scratch and contain none of the values from the previous page.

Common methods for saving some state from one page that you can use in other pages are:

1. Storing the value in a cookie
2. Storing the value in local storage (only modern browsers)
3. Storing the value on a server where the web pages can retrieve it

Comment: If all the methods and variables in js file is encapsulated, can I avoid the issue... (I guess not... )
Sorry, is any alternative approach beside the above 3? Because I develop the system on mobile system, the local storage is very inconvenient. Thank u.

Comment: @Stallman - The lifetime of javascript state is as I explained and is not changed by encapsulation in a js file in any way.  I think perhaps you didn't understand what I meant by Local Storage (it works quite well on mobile).  It is a storage mechanism built into the browser and is part of HTML5.  See http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html for more info.

Comment: On PC, do developers always use cache to address the common issue, or anything else?  How about on the mobile system? 
I have experience in using the local storage via "PhoneGap", but it always lets me down. Too much bug waits to be fixed. Thank u.

Comment: @Stallman - you asked about "cache" to address the issue, but I don't understand what you mean by that.  The most common solution to this issue is cookies or server-wide storage because both of those work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The edit_story_name.html is opened in a new window and all variables from the old window will be lost as the DOM is reloaded in the new window.

Comment: Ok, see I was just a bit late.. See jfriend00's answer.